# WHERE value IS NOT IN (subquery)

Tags: mysql, subquery

I've been struggling with this query.
I have two tables. One with coupons and Invoicenumbers. One with Invoicenumbers and customer names.

I need to get the customers who have not used a given coupon.

Here are the tables:

Promotion table:

```
Promotions
Invoice | Coupon
----------------
1       | couponA
2       | couponB
3       | couponB
```

Orders Table:

```
Orders
Invoice | Customer
------------------
1       | Jack
2       | Jack
3       | Jill
```

So Jack has used coupons A and B. And Jill has only used coupon B.

If my query were select customers who have not used coupon A, I should get Jill.

This works, but it seems clumsy and slow. Is there a better way?

```
SELECT Customer 
FROM Promotions INNER JOIN Orders
ON Promotions.Invoice = Orders.Invoice
WHERE Customer NOT IN(
    SELECT Customer 
    FROM Promotions INNER JOIN Orders
    ON Promotions.Invoice = Orders.Invoice
    WHERE Coupon = couponA)
GROUP BY Customer
```

Thanks for looking!

edit:
Here's an SQLFiddle schema
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21d31/6

Comment: Are you still seeking a solution or does one if the answers work?

Answer (score 5):

**Updated:** We should use prefer to use joins for better performance when its easy to do for us. [Join vs. sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query#answer-2577188)

#### Sql Fiddle

```
Select distinct Customer from orders o
join 
(
  SELECT distinct Customer as changedname FROM Orders o2 
  join
  (
     Select distinct invoice from Promotions where Coupon='couponA'
  ) t3
  on o2.invoice = t3.invoice      
) t2
on o.customer != t2.changedname;
```

Note: I changed column name customer for t3 because two joined tables must have different column names

**Explanation:**

Using inner or sub query is expensive when you have big data. use joins instead, lets learn converting subquery to join

With **Subquery** We had:

```
Select distinct Customer from orders where customer not in 
(SELECT distinct Customer FROM Orders where invoice in
(Select distinct invoice from Promotions where Coupon='couponA'));
```

**Converting sub-query to join**

First step:

```
Select distinct Customer from orders o
join 
(
  SELECT distinct Customer as changedname FROM Orders where invoice in
  (Select distinct invoice from Promotions where Coupon='couponA')
) t2
on o.customer != t2.changedname;
```

2nd step:

```
Select distinct Customer from orders o
join 
(
  SELECT distinct Customer as changedname FROM Orders o2 where invoice 
  join
  (
     Select distinct invoice from Promotions where Coupon='couponA'
  ) t3
  on o2.invoice = t3.invoice      
) t2
on o.customer != t2.changedname;
```

And that's it, much faster for tables having numerous rows

**Original answer:**

Use `not in`. Have a look.

```
Select distinct Customer from orders where customer not in 
(SELECT distinct Customer FROM Orders where invoice in
(Select distinct invoice from Promotions where Coupon='couponA'));
```

**Edit** I have added distinct to make query faster

#### SQL Fiddle

Comment: Tried a simple query without any join which will fetch your desired result and not bad with efficiency as well. I Can explain if any problem.

Comment: This works in the Fiddle, but when I try it on my real data (which includes 10k-20k records) it times out.

Comment: @TimSum. I have added distinct to make query faster. Check it now.

Answer (score 4):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT o2.customer FROM ORDER o2 
LEFT JOIN (promotions p1 
    JOIN Orders o1 ON p1.cuopon = 'CuoponA' AND p1.invoice = o1.invoice ) p3 
    ON o2.customer = p3.customer 
WHERE p3.customer IS NULL
```

Comment: After adjusting the spelling, I still get this error, "Unknown column 'p1.Coupon' in 'where clause'"

Comment: `Select 
distinct customer 
from order 
left join promotions p1 on p1.cuopon = 'CuoponA' and 
p1.invoice = order.invoice
where p1.coupon is null`

Comment: add p1 as alias for promotions table

Comment: After fixing Lot of mistake. `Select distinct customer from orders left outer join promotions p1
on p1.coupon = 'CouponA' and p1.invoice = orders.invoice
where p1.coupon is null` Still wrong result

Comment: `SELECT 
DISTINCT o2.customer 
FROM ORDER o2
LEFT JOIN (promotions p1 JOIN Orders o1 ON p1.cuopon = 'CuoponA' AND 
p1.invoice = o1.invoice ) p3 ON o2.customer = p3.customer 
WHERE p3.customer IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Try this query instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer
FROM Orders o1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Orders o2
    INNER JOIN Promotions ON Promotions.Invoice = o2.Invoice
    WHERE o1.Customer = o2.Customer AND Coupon = 'couponB')
```

The idea is to get rid of the `GROUP BY` by removing a join in the top part of the query, and also eliminate the `NOT IN` by making a *coordinated subquery*.

[Here is a link to sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21d31/35)

Comment: I can't get this to work correctly. I recently put up a SQLFiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Try this with a right join

```
SELECT Customer, Coupon
FROM Promotions 
RIGHT JOIN Orders ON Promotions.Invoice = Orders.Invoice
    AND Coupon = 'couponA'
GROUP BY Customer
HAVING Coupon IS NULL
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work when I try it on my actual data. It's filtering out the Invoices that include 'CouponA', but I need the whole customer kept from the results. This worked in the Fiddle at first, but when I switched the order of the coupons (from A,B,B to B,A,B) it did not work.