# Using PDO/MySQL to only show items with an ID that is not is a different table with the same ID

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get a list to only display user missions that are not already done, I have a table that is setup to collect completed user missions. However I can only get it to not display only either the first one or the last one in the results for selecting the Missions ID from the User Missions Completed table.

I have tried using sub queries to no avail, have tried using different reductions and loops to collect the ID's into an array

```
$db->query("SELECT mID FROM user_missions_complete WHERE userid = ?");
$db->execute([$user_class->id]);
$get = $db->fetch();
foreach($get as $g) {
    $mID = $g['mID'];
}
$db->query("SELECT * FROM `daily_missions` WHERE ID != ? ORDER BY `id` ASC");
$db->execute([$mID]);
$m = $db->fetch();

foreach($m as $mis) {
    echo "
        <tr>
            "; if($mis['task_one'] != 'N/A') { echo "
            "; } if($mis['task_two'] != 'N/A') { echo "
            "; } if($mis['task_three'] != 'N/A') { echo "
            "; } if($mis['task_four'] != 'N/A') { echo "
            "; } if($mis['task_five'] != 'N/A') { echo "
            "; } if($mis['task_six'] != 'N/A') { echo "
            "; } if($mis['task_seven'] != 'N/A') { echo "
            "; } if($mis['task_eight'] != 'N/A') { echo "
            "; } echo "
        </tr>";
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is for the list of missions from daily_missions to only show on the page results/missions that are not already completed and inside the user_missions_complete table. However, it is only either not including the first result or the last result in the query results.

Comment: by the way, shouldn't you use join statements instead, i think you meant to use `->prepare()` there instead

Comment: Can you please add sample data and what should be returned? This seems more like a `mysql` question.

Comment: Have a look through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017369/where-value-is-not-in-subquery as you can do this in 1 SQL statement and that will make it easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

With this :

```
foreach($get as $g) {
    $mID = $g['mID'];
}
```

you aren't doing the execute every time so you are only saving the last id which means that :

```
WHERE ID != ?
```

is only using the last value (whichever way round you order your results).

Also you are using  `$db->fetch();` which only returns a single row.  You want to use `$db->fetchAll();`

I think you should be able to do this in a single query as has been suggested.  You should make use of `INNER JOIN` - without knowing your table structure I would hazard a guess at :

```
SELECT * FROM daily_missions dm
INNER JOIN user_missions_complete umc ON (dm.id = umc.mID)
WHERE dm.userid = ?
```

So you final code would look something similar to:

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM daily_missions dm
            INNER JOIN user_missions_complete umc ON (dm.id = umc.mID)
            WHERE dm.userid = ?");
$db->execute([$user_class->id]);
$m = $db->fetchAll();
```

then you can loop through the whole list of results.

Naturally you'll need to check your table relationships and column names but this should but you on a better track.

Also if you do need to filter out mysql results based on multiple values you should look into using the `WHERE IN(` and/or `HAVING` clauses